# ggplot2 comparation of time period

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, period

I need to visualize and compare the difference in two equally long sales periods. 2018/2019 and 2019/2020. Both periods begin at week 44 and end at week 36 of the following year. If I create a graph, both periods are continuous and line up. If I use only the week number, the values ​​are sorted as continuum and the graph does not make sense. Can you think of a solution?

Thank You

Data:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(sells = runif(44),
                  week = c(44:52,1:35),
                  YW = yearweek(seq(as.Date("2018-11-01"), as.Date("2019-08-31"), by = "1 week")),
                  period = "18/19")

df2 <- data.frame(sells = runif(44),
                  week = c(44:52,1:35),
                  YW = yearweek(seq(as.Date("2019-11-01"), as.Date("2020-08-31"), by = "1 week")),
                  period = "19/20")

# Yearweek on x axis, when both period are separated

ggplot(df1, aes(YW, sells)) +
  geom_line(aes(color="Period 18/19")) + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(color="Period 19/20")) +
  labs(color="Legend text")

# week on x axis when weeks are like continuum and not splited by year
ggplot(df1, aes(week, sells)) +
  geom_line(aes(color="Period 18/19")) + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(color="Period 19/20")) +
  labs(color="Legend text")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the x axis as a numeric scale, you can do:

```r
ggplot(df1, aes((week + 9) %% 52, sells)) +
  geom_line(aes(color="Period 18/19")) + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(color="Period 19/20")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:52,
                     labels = function(x) ifelse(x == 9, 52, (x - 9) %% 52), 
                     name = "week") +
  labs(color="Legend text")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm working with your solution, but I noticed one thing. The x-axis shows 0 insted 52. Still not able figure out the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to facet it. This'll require combining the two sets into one, preserving the data source. (This is commonly a better way of dealing with it in general, anyway.)

(I don't have `tstibble`, so my `YW` just has `seq(...)`, no `yearweek`. It should translate.)

```r
ggplot(dplyr::bind_rows(tibble::lst(df1, df2), .id = "id"), aes(YW, sells)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = id)) +
  facet_wrap(id ~ ., scales = "free_x", ncol = 1)
```

[image: faceted ggplot2]

In place of `dplyr::bind_rows`, one might also use `data.table::rbindlist(..., idcol="id")`, or `do.call(rbind, ...)`, though with the latter you will need to assign `id` externally.

One more note: the default formatting of the x-axis is obscuring the "year" of the data. If this is relevant/important (and not apparent elsewhere), then use `ggplot2`'s normal mechanism for forcing labels, e.g.,

```r
... +
  scale_x_date(labels = function(z) format(z, "%Y-%m"))
```

[image: faceted ggplot2 with updated x-axis labels]

While unlikely that you can do this without having `tibble::lst` available, you can replace that with `list(df1=df1, df2=df2)` or similar.

Comment: Yes, I think this is nicest on the eye and has the clearest x axis labelling.

Comment: I agree ... and I know there are times when direct overlap is desired in order to see minute vertical differences between the lines. We lose that dimension a little with this, though macro differences should be evident-enough given the same y-axis limits.

Comment: Oops, `tibble::lst`, thanks. Fixed/noted.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, your solution is visually the cleanest, but in the nature of the data and the customer =D I have to use a comparison in one graph to clearly see the difference in sales periods

Comment: I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can format your week variable as a factor and keep the desired order. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)
#Data
df1$week <- factor(df1$week,levels = unique(df1$week),ordered = T)
df2$week <- factor(df2$week,levels = unique(df2$week),ordered = T)
#Plot
ggplot(df1, aes(week, sells)) +
  geom_line(aes(color="Period 18/19",group=1)) + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(color="Period 19/20",group=1)) +
  labs(color="Legend text")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I tried something similar. I put the week as a factor in the ggplot, but it didn't work. Thank you once again